# How to retrieve google play games ID with the new updated Google play games Gamer ID?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I have used Google play unity package for google play Service sign In. Using the profile ID(generated at sign In) I have identified the users.But as of now,the updated google Play games generates new profile ID(which starts with 'g') for the same User.Is there a way for me to identify the old profile Id using the updated Google Play Games Gamer ID.

Answer (score 6):

The short answer is there is no public way to map the Google+ ids to the gamer ids. If this is affecting an existing game that you have published, you should get in touch with your Google Business Development contact (if you know who that is), or add you information to [this form](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/forms/d/1kWr9AXL3wMv_yjrjH7U-mAyDK6nfeFE5sicEQraLn6I/viewform) which will get you in contact with someone who can help.

Comment: So, you guys(am I right, Clayton, that you work at Google right with this feature?), silently replace id's for players within already installed games with progress? In your documentation I've seen that this ID will never change, at least [here](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity#retrieving-players-email-or-a-unique-identifier) _"This is a unique ID specific to that player and is the same value all the time"_

Comment: Yes, I work at Google in Developer Relations with Games. The documentation is true, except in this case which should be a 1 time thing. If you are not persisting the ids externally, your game will work with no changes.

Comment: Any chances to provide API to solve this problem for us(game developers)? We are persisting this ids on our servers, and I think it is normal since there was no any attention that they should not be persisted. And sorry, but _same value all the time_  is not the same as _same value all the time except 1 time change_.

Comment: Don't apologize for stating the obvious :).    Please reach out and discuss your situation via BD or the form linked above.